# odoo 9 - how to properly inherit views when using prototype inheritance

Tags: xml, inheritance, view, odoo, prototype

I have this parent model :

```
class TodoTask(models.Model):
    _name = 'todo.taskmyown'
    name = fields.Char('Description', required=True)
    is_done = fields.Boolean('Done?')
    active = fields.Boolean('Active?', default=True)
```

and the child model :

```
class TodoTask(models.Model):
    _name='todo.tasktest'
    _inherit=['todo.taskmyown', 'mail.thread']
    user_id = fields.Many2one('res.users', 'Responsible')
    date_deadline = fields.Date('Deadline')
    name = fields.Char(help="What needs to be done?")
```

the parent view :

```html
<record id="view_form_todo_task" model="ir.ui.view">
  <field name="name">To-do Task Form</field>
  <field name="model">todo.taskmyown</field>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
   <form string="To-do Task">
    <sheet>
    <group name="group_top">
     <group name="group_left">
     <field name="name"/>
     </group>
     <group name="group_right">
     <field name="is_done"/>
     <field name="active" readonly="1"/>
     </group>
    </group>
    </sheet>
   </form>
</field>
</record>
```

child view :

```html
<record id="view_form_todo_tasktest_inherited" model="ir.ui.view">
  <field name="model">todo.tasktest</field>
  <field name="inherit_id" ref="myOwnTodo_app.view_form_todo_task"/>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
   <sheet position="after">
    <div class="oe_chatter">
    <field name="message_follower_ids" widget="mail_followers" />
    <field name="message_ids" widget="mail_thread" />
    </div>
   </sheet>
   <field name="name" position="after">
    <field name="user_id" />
   </field>
   <field name="is_done" position="before">
    <field name="date_deadline" />
   </field>
  </field>
</record>
```

my problem is that when i browse to child view's UI , i see the UI of the parent view instead, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have record with *Complete ID* `myOwnTodo_app.view_form_todo_task` in Settings->Technical->Sequences & Identifiers->External Identifiers ?

Comment: yes i do have the complete ID, may i add that when i define 'todo.taskmyown' as the value for the child's _name it works fine